# Adding BarButtons to a UINavigationBar after presenting a modal view controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using the template for a utility Application. In the FlipSideViewController, I added an IBOutlet for a UINavigationController, navController.  In the code, I added the navController just fine.  The rootViewController loads perfectly:

```
navController.viewControllers = [[NSArray arrayWithObject:rootViewController] retain];
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
```

I changed the color of the navController just fine:

```
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.75 blue:0.6 alpha:1.0];
navController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

I make a button (note: "done" refers to a IBAction that dismisses the modalviewcontroller):

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done:)];
```

I make a navItem using that button:

```
UINavigationItem *backNavItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TESTTEST"];
[backNavItem setRightBarButtonItem:backButton animated:YES];
```

I try to add that button:

```
[navController.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:backNavItem animated:YES];
```

This above code fails miserably.  I apparently can't add buttons to the navController because:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Cannot call
>   pushNavigationItem:animated: directly
>   on a UINavigationBar managed by a
>   controller.'

Do I have to make a separate UINavigationBar that's somehow connected to my navController?  I tried going that route but with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked out "NavBar" [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/NavBar/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418):

Excellent insight on how to do add buttons.  You have to add buttons from the correct ViewController being displayed.