# UINavigationController with custom NavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create a `UINavigationController` with a customized `NavigationBar`.

I've created a class (myNavBar), which inherits from `UINavigationBar`.

I call my `navigationController` like this :

```
UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[myNavBar class] toolbarClass:[UIToolbar class]];
[navControl pushViewController:myVewController animated:NO];
```

But I get this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot call setItems:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'
```

What's wrong in my code.

**UPDATE**

Here is myNavigationBar class :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myNavBar : UINavigationBar

-(void)initNavBarButtons:(UIViewController*)sender;

@end


---------------------------------------------------


#import "myNavBar.h"

@implementation myNavBar
{
    UIButton *menuButton;
    UIButton *searchButton;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Do any additional setup
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)initNavBarButtons:(UIViewController*)sender
{
    [menuButton addTarget:sender action:@selector(revealMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [searchButton addTarget:sender action:@selector(revealSearch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}


- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}

-(id)init
{   self = [super init];
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self setFrame:rect];

    //[self setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

    menuButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 22);
    [menuButton setCenter:CGPointMake(25, self.center.y)];
    [menuButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setHidden:NO];
    [self addSubview:menuButton];

    UIImageView *zblogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"minilogo.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 25)]];
    UINavigationItem *navI = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    [self setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navI]];

    [self.topItem setTitleView:zblogo];

    searchButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    searchButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
    [searchButton setCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width - 25, self.center.y)];
    [searchButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boutonRecherche.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self addSubview:searchButton];
}


@end
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Now my NavigationController is well instantiated, but I still having a problem :
If I write

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[myNavBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
[navController setViewControllers:@[vc] animated:NO]
```

everything I've done in the initialization of my bar is remove, and with

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[myNavBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
[navController pushViewController:vc animated:NO]
```

my navigationBar appears with a "back button", and I see my customization by clicking on it.

I've read this topic : [Why does using setViewControllers remove everything from the UINavigationController's nav bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362094/why-does-using-setviewcontrollers-remove-everything-from-the-uinavigationcontrol) but it doesn't really help me.

How could I preserve my navigationBar as it is initially set?

Comment: does your `myVewController` have another `UINavigationBar` inside?

Comment: Don't do anything in `drawRect`! Adding views or setting frame shouldn't be in `drawRect` Put it into `init`!

Comment: I've remove code from drawRect, and now i've nothing in my navigationBar, neither if I put my code in init, nor in initWithFrame:. Those two methods are never called...

Comment: When subclassing a `UIView` you should override `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:`. One of them should be called.

Comment: That's right. initWithCoder is called when my view are load from storyboard with a navigationBar set as a myNavBar in the Identy inspector, and initWithFrame is called when I use initWithNavigationBarClass:. Although I manage to set my titleView in initWithCoder: , I don't in initWithFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have to put **nil** in the second parameter (the toolbar one) to use the default one?

From the docs:

> *Specify the custom UIToolbar subclass you want to use, **or specify nil** to use the standard UIToolbar class.*

**Update**, after checking I think the problem goes more into this direction, please check those links:

[How to add Button in UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582587/how-to-add-button-in-uinavigationcontroller)

[Adding BarButtons to a UINavigationBar after presenting a modal view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569340/adding-barbuttons-to-a-uinavigationbar-after-presenting-a-modal-view-controller)

Comment: No, it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I just try to do an empty project like yours and it is working for me, which makes me think that the problem is in another place. Some piece of information is missing here. Go ahead an try with an empty project.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to put image in your navigation bar , then try this .. in your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching method

```
if ([self.navCtrl.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"];
        [self.navCtrligationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
```

Comment: No, I'm not just including an image.

I'm doing an app with a sliding menu. I'm using ECSlidingViewController.

So I've build my app with the storyboard, using the Storyboard ID (and Restoration ID) to call my controllers. Each of them have a navigationBAr displayed on top.

The menu is a TableView, and its didSelectRowAtIndexPath method calls the controllers I want to show.
And especially, one of those I want to show will be a table with a push transition.